# Why didn't they shrink plants like humans?

Tags: downsizing-2017

In Sci-fi movie *Downsizing (2017)*,  Paul offers Dusan a rose:

[image]

Why didn't they shrink plants like humans?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the very beginning we know that it is possible to downsize plants because Dr. Jorgen Asbjornsen says “a wide array of flora and fauna were subjected in this process and with the exception of some fish and shellfish, absolutely no side effects were detected.”

There seem to be plenty of examples of downsized plants that we see throughout the movie. Leisureland Estates (and specifically Paul’s neighborhood) is filled with trees, grass, and other plants for example.

It would be difficult to cultivate flowers under the dome due to the lack of insects (being both pollinators and a food source for non-insect pollinators), but it’s still possible, such as with [hand pollination](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hand-pollination).

The rose we see was bought from the Full-Sized Flower Mart, which most likely imports flowers from the full-sized world precisely because it would be so cool to have a giant flower.

Comment: **DUSAN:** *No! Is that a rose? A real rose? From where you get a real rose?*
**PAUL:** *New store. Full-Sized Flower Mart.*
**DUSAN**: *Here in Leisureland? Why did I not have such a brilliant idea? How much
they are charging for this?* - http://www.dailyscript.com/scripts/downsizing.pdf